# Where can I access debug mode on android studio?

Tags: debugging, android-studio, ide

I am confused with the layout of android studio and am going blind from the amount of options within this IDE.
I am looking for someone who can point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you see the green bug at the top bar? Just click on that to debug your app.